# Issue with format and lists

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, windows-7, string-formatting

I have a loop where I change a list and then using `format` build a new string. When using this line

```
strCommand = strCommand.format(*strCmdVars)
```

I found that the string wouldn't update as I iterated through my data, `strCommand` would remain with its original value. However when I changed it to this

```
strCmd = strCommand.format(*strCmdVars)
```

things started working as expected.
Did I stumble onto something weird, or was I doing something wrong the first time around? 
This is running under Python Version 3.4.3 on Windows 7.
Here are some specifics to work with:

`strCommand = "show run {0} access-list {1}"
strCmdVars = ["ipv6","FWG31"]`

In the actual script I initialize strCmdVars using append like this

`strCmdVars.append(parts1)
strCmdVars.append(parts2)`

Then as I iterate through a file I'm reading in (which is where the value of parts1 and parts2 is from) at the end of the loop I do

`strCmdVars[0]=parts1
strCmdVars[1]=parts2`

My examples are extrapolations for sake of simplification. As I am looping through the file strCmdVars could hold any of these values:
ipv6,FWG31
ipv4,FWG32
ipv4,FWG33
ipv6,FWG34
ipv4,FWG31
etc.
I verified that the value of strCmdVars was indeed changing to the correct values, using dbp debugging, and that the value of strCommand was not changing and remaining at it's initial value.

Comment: Very weird. Could you edit your question with a concrete example (values for `strCmdVars ` and `strCommand `) so we can run it and tested in our side?

Comment: Edited the question and provided much more details, with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just dawned on me what I did wrong and why my fix worked, sometimes you just have to sleep on it to figure it out :-P OK follow along here.
Initial value of `strCommand = "show run {0} access-list {1}"`
then I use the format function to substitute {0} and {1} with actual values, say "IPv6" and "FWG32".
Now `strCommand = "show run IPV6 access-list FWG32"`
See the issue??? No more {0} and {1} !!! :-D